# Correct format of an equation

Tags: equations

I have this equation:

```
\begin{equation}
B_{1} = 0.9(B_{2})  + \\ 
\bigg[ 
   \sqrt{(x_{1}^2 + y_{1}^2 + z_{1}^2)}-\sqrt{(x_{2}^2 + y_{2}^2 + z_{2}^2)} 
\bigg] 
\end{equation}
```

I heard the `B_{1}` is some kind of result (like a sum, product, etc.) and must be declared as such, so TeX applies the math style guide - correct appearance on it.

But I dont know what it is and how to mark it. Which command can I use here?

Comment: Do you mean summation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a line break in an `equation` environment, so the `\\` does nothing.

A better way to type the equation could be

```
\begin{equation}
B_{1} = 0.9\,B_{2} + \Bigl[
        \sqrt{(x_{1}^2 + y_{1}^2 + z_{1}^2)}-
        \sqrt{(x_{2}^2 + y_{2}^2 + z_{2}^2)} \; \Bigr] 
\end{equation}
```

so that the various components of the equation are more visible.

I've made a couple of changes:

- `\Bigl[` for the opening bracket and `\Bigr]` for the closing one (as `\bigg` size seems too much). Notice the final `l` or `r` to declare the type of delimiter;
- a thin space `\,` between the decimal number `0.9` and `B_{2}` (which I wouldn't put in parentheses), as the result of `0.9B_{2}` might be confusing;
- a thick space between the second square root and the closing bracket for symmetry with the space at the start.

There is no special way to mark `B_{1}`: it's just a symbol with a subscript.

[image]

Comment: this is very helpful, but my prof really told me the B_{1} can´t be italic because it´s something different like the "x" which would be correct as italic. I mean it must be something like a special type of result that mathematicans wouldnt write italic.

Comment: I don't really know: you should look in the literature in your field in order to see what's the usual form. Maybe `\mathrm{B}_{1}`?

Comment: or `\mathbf{B}_{1}`?

Comment: I will use that, thank you! I was hoping someone could tell me how you would call the "B", but I guess I should go to maths.stackexchange for that. Thank you guys!

Comment: @dan With french notations, we need to use `\usepackage[upright]{fourier}`. I think some other packages for fonts have this option (upright)

Comment: The `B` is probably some kind of operator, right? Depending on the subfield you're in, in addition to the `\mathrm{B}` and `\mathbf{B}` possibilities already mentioned, you may also want to try out `\mathcal{B}`; for that, you may have to add an extra fonts package such as `amsfonts`.

Comment: for an operator to be typeset as such (similar to log), you can declare it in the preamble. e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}` - then \diag in math will typeset "diag" upright